# The selenium webscrapper I built for linked in isn't collecting any links as it is supposed

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

```
for page in range(2,14):
    time.sleep(5)
    job_block = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "scaffold-layout__list-container")
    time.sleep(5)
    jobs_list = job_block.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".scaffold-layout__list-container-item")
    time.sleep(5)
    for job in jobs_list:
        all_links = job.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
        for a in all_links:
            if (str(a.get_attribute('href')).startswith("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view") and a.get_attribute('href') not in links):
                links.append(a.get_attribute('href'))
    # Scroll to the next page
    button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ember222']/button")
    button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
print('Found'+str(len(links))+'links for the job offer)
```

above is the basic loop of code
And the expected output is supposed to be the number of links visited but the output I am currently getting is "Found 0 links for the job offer". I have even tried changing position of the print statements as well as the scroll to the next page statements as well everything leads to an error.
Please give me some insight on this.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, add a tag for the programming language you are using.